Printing PDF with N pages in QGIS Server
At present, I can only print one page using a template. However, I aim to enhance my capabilities by dynamically printing multiple pages using the same template.
I tried but didn't work :
http://localhost:8080/qgis-server/?
SERVICE=WMS
&LAYERS=hidden
&VERSION=1.3.0
&REQUEST=GetPrint
&FORMAT=pdf
&CRS=EPSG:2154
&TEMPLATE=Basic
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_GEOM=POLYGON((x1 y1, x2 y2, x3 y3, x4 y4, x1 y1));POLYGON((x5 y5, x6 y6, x7 y7, x8 y8, x5 y5));POLYGON((x9 y9, x10 y10, x11 y11, x12 y12, x9 y9))
&map0:EXTENT=xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_SYMBOL=<StyledLayerDescriptor><UserStyle><Name>Highlight</Name><FeatureTypeStyle><Rule><Name>Symbol</Name><LineSymbolizer><Stroke><CssParameter name="stroke">%23ea1173</CssParameter><CssParameter name="stroke-opacity">1</CssParameter><CssParameter name="stroke-width">1.6</CssParameter></Stroke></LineSymbolizer><PolygonSymbolizer><Fill><CssParameter name="fill">%23FFFF00</CssParameter><CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</CssParameter></Fill></PolygonSymbolizer></Rule></FeatureTypeStyle></UserStyle></StyledLayerDescriptor>
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_LABELSTRING=Write label here
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_LABELSIZE=16
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_LABELCOLOR=%23000000
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_LABELBUFFERCOLOR=%23FFFFFF
&map0:HIGHLIGHT_LABELBUFFERSIZE=1.5
&map1:HIGHLIGHT_GEOM=POLYGON((...))
&map1:EXTENT=...
&map1:HIGHLIGHT_SYMBOL=...
&map1:HIGHLIGHT_LABELSTRING=...
&map1:HIGHLIGHT_LABELCOLOR=...
&map1:HIGHLIGHT_LABELBUFFERCOLOR=...
&map1:HIGHLIGHT_LABELBUFFERSIZE=...
&map1:HIGHLIGHT_LABELSIZE=...
&map2:HIGHLIGHT_GEOM=POLYGON((...))
&map2:EXTENT=...
&map2:HIGHLIGHT_SYMBOL=...
&map2:HIGHLIGHT_LABELSTRING=...
&map2:HIGHLIGHT_LABELCOLOR=...
&map2:HIGHLIGHT_LABELBUFFERCOLOR=...
&map2:HIGHLIGHT_LABELBUFFERSIZE=...
&map2:HIGHLIGHT_LABELSIZE=...


With QGIS-server you to do it your self by doing a loop and generate your page one by one then merged all the pdfs.
